# Am I passing an object to object.defineProperties?

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript and would love help understanding the snippet of code.

From [Object.DefineProperties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) definition, the first parameter is an object. Is MyObjectConstructor a declaration or an object. With a constructor function I would expect to call **new** to make it an object.

This is what is confusing me. Or as I read in Javascript functions are objects so do I treat it as an object and the **this** property is where all staticProps and instanceProps are added to?

```
var _prototypeProperties = function (child, staticProps, instanceProps) {
   if (staticProps){ 
       Object.defineProperties(child, staticProps)
   };
    if (instanceProps) { 
     Object.defineProperties(child.prototype, instanceProps);
   }
  };

function myFunction() {
    function MyObjectConstructor(element) {
      this.element = element;
      this.initialized = false;
    }

  _prototypeProperties(MyObjectConstructor, {...}, {...});
}
```

Comment: No, the constructor is an object in itself (try `FooConstructor.a =1`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, (constructor) functions are objects as well in javascript, and you can add properties directly to them.

The `_prototypeProperties` function in your example snippet does put the `staticProperties` on the constructor, so that they could be accessed as `MyObjectConstructor.myStaticProperty`. It also does put `instanceProps` (better: "class properties", "prototype properties") on the `MyObjectConstructor.prototype` object, from where they are inherited by instances: `(new MyObjectConstructor).myPrototypeProperty`. Lastly, your `MyObjectConstructor` does put "real" (own) properties on the instances, specifically `(new MyObjectConstructor).element`  and `.initialised`.

Comment: Thank you Bergi, with your reply and others a lot more is clear. Okay, functions are first class objects. So what is the 'this' value? Do a function has its own 'this' value?

Comment: No, `this` is a special identifier (variable?) that is set by the caller of the function. If you call the function as a constructor, `this` will refer to the new instance; so `.element` and `.initialised` will be created as own properties of the new object by the constructor. Read more about `this` [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) or [on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/1048572)

Comment: Can you look at : https://github.com/PWKad/aurelia-samples/blob/master/src/chord-diagram.js. Are you saying that outside of this file, 'this' has been set?

Comment: What do you mean by "outside of the file"? `this` is only used in functions/methods usually. Where it points to the object that the method was called on, e.g. when you invoke `obj.method()` then inside `function method(){…` the `this` value is `obj`

Comment: Sorry, it is clearer now what you mean. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

first : the `function` is the `first type object` in the javascript . it means you can deliver the function as value . for example :

```
function test(){

    return function(){
        console.log('function');
    }
}

test()();
```

you return the function as return an object , function can be assigned and the function another kind of value !

```
var test = function(i) {
    // body...
    return i;
}

test('123');
```

a character string 'test' refer to a Anonymous function , you can understand that you transmit a function to a character string .

second : if you use `new` to create a instance via function , this function will be called `construction function` , normally it used to init the params , and the instance will take the construction function own property or method and prototype's property or method from the construction function .

third : the instance's property of "`__proto__`" is refer to the construction function's prototype object . this is why the instance can use the prototype's property or method from the construction function .

forth : if you create the instance by `new` , the `this` will refer to the instance object ! so that instance can use the property and method .

from your code :

```
var _prototypeProperties = function (child, staticProps, instanceProps) {
   if (staticProps){ 
       Object.defineProperties(child, staticProps)
   };
   // the properties from the own construction function  , like this :
   //  this.element = element;
   //  this.initialized = false;


    if (instanceProps) { 
     Object.defineProperties(child.prototype, instanceProps);
   }
  };

  // the properties from the construction function's prototype object . like this :
  //   MyObjectConstructor.prototype.name = 'somebody';
  //   MyObjectConstructor.prototype.getName = function(){
  //        return this.name;
  //   }
```

Comment: "*the first type object*" - what does that mean?

Comment: for example :
function test(){

 return function(){
  console.log('function');
 }
}

test()();
you can return `function` as return `object` , the `function` can be delivered as the object in the javascript

Comment: Yes, functions are objects; though "function as the object" doesn't make much sense. Your statement "*the function is the first type object in the javascript*" just doesn't parse with my English grammar.

Comment: sorry , actually i am a china guy , and my english is not good enough , i edit the answer , maybe you can get it from my answer ...

Comment: I think @qianjiahao means "first class object"

Comment: @qianjiahao : Thank you for the information you provided. It has helped me immensely.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, once defined, the resulting functions act identically:

```
function Hat() { }
var Hat = function() { }
```

Conventionally the first is used to create objects (usually with `new`) and the second is used as a regular method.

The `new` operator, when preceding a function gets kinda weird. Using the `new` operator will:

- create a new Object "it"
- set the function being called as "it"s prototype
- binds "it" to `this` within the function
- overrides the return value of the function with "it". This overrides both explicit returns and implicit returns of `undefined`.

For example:

```
// first define Hat function
function Hat() { this.color = 'red' }

// calling with `new` implicitly returns a new object bound to the function
new Hat()
// > Hat { color: "red" }

// invoking without `new` implicitly returns `unefined`,
// but `this` points to Hat's parent object.
// If running in the browser, Hat's parent object would be `window`
// so now Window.color is set to "red"
Hat()
//> undefined
Window.color
//> "red"
```

Be careful with `new`, because the new object will be returned instead of any explicit returns.

```
var color = function() { return "blue" }
color()
//> "blue"
new color()
//> color {}
```

JavaScript is prototypal by nature. The `new` operator reflects neither prototypical nor classical inheritance. I avoid it when possible, although many popular libraries use it.

I recommend reading through Crockford's explanation of JavaScript's prototypal inheritance: http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

Its terse, but if you understand his 10 lines of demo code you'll be good.

Play with `bind`, `call` and `apply`, and different scoping contexts too. After understanding scoping and the prototypal nature, the rest is just syntax.

Comment: Thanks, @Bergi, edited. Its hard to gauge the right depth in answers, especially to someone new to a language.

Comment: @Matthew. Thank you for the information you provided. Your 'this' example made perfect sense.